# Save blank record

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to get the ID of my new record after I save it. 
Cause I need it to save controls that are not bound to the record.

So I did it like this.

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()

 If IsNull(SalesCallID) Then
    DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, , acMenuVer70
    SalesCallID.Requery
    MsgBox SalesCallID
 End If
```

`SalesCallID` is a textbox bound on the id of the record.
So if it's `null`, I save and I update it.
But if the person changed only unbound controls, it won't save. then I won't be able to get the ID.

I tried to set the form dirty like this `Me.Dirty = true`
but it's not working.

I could on the `open form` event insert a space in the comment field... but is there a more elegant way to resolve that problem?

Thank you

Comment: For the most part, it is useful to have an updated date, you could include one and update it via code with the save button. You have to complete at least one table field to get a new record, unless you want to add a record via sql or a recordset, which may lead to more problems.

Comment: You are right, I got that already. A `createdBy` and a `createdDate` why it's not saving then. It should save cause they are bound

Comment: I would imagine that you have set a default value for them rather than completing them via code. `Me.txtCreateBy = "Marc"`

Comment: oh yeah, for the default value I call a method GetUser(). So I should do it in the code instead?

Comment: A default value is nice, but you are looking for a fiddle on a form where a user can get away with not completing any entries, so for a fiddle, completing in code should work.

Comment: It works, thank you! As usual another quality answer from you. Can you write it as an answer so you can have your points plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, it is useful to have an updated date, you could include one and update it via code with the save button. You have to complete at least one table field to get a new record, unless you want to add a record via sql or a recordset, which may lead to more problems. If you are looking for a fiddle, a default value will not work, you need something like:

```
Me.txtCreateBy = "Marc"
```